# Is there a way to block the insert of a record

Tags: soql

Is there a way to stop the inserting of a record in a trigger for an object? Users want to block the creation of a task that is generated when there is an e-mail to case event. Can I stop a record from being inserted in a before insert trigger for the Task object or do I have to let it be inserted and then delete it either in the after insert or using a job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking the task in a `before insert` trigger will cause the email-to-case process to fail (e.g. the comment also won't be logged, and system administrators will be notified by email instead). Instead, use an after insert trigger to call a `@future` method that will delete the task.

Comment: Given that, I might as well just schedule an Apex job to clean them up. Though this might be better because someone would only see the e-mail task for a short instant.

Comment: That's the point of using asynchronous code. In fact, in practice, unless you're using the streaming API to monitor these tasks, it's entirely likely you'll never see the task (i.e. the process should complete in less than a second after the prior transaction completes)... just as if it had never existed at all.

Comment: I created a helper class with a static method that receives the Id as a parameter and it seems to work great. The thing to remember is that you have a limit of 200 future calls per user license. It looks to me that I shouldn't hit this limit so I'll go with this. If you think  you'll reach the limit, it would be better to clean them up in an Apex job.